# Hive: Copy table structure to another cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive

Is there an easy way to duplicate the structure (but not the data) of my hive database/tables from one Hadoop cluster to another?

I've been looking for something similar to the way `mysqldump` exports DDL but haven't found anything that I could use readily automate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily do a show create table like below.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE myTable;
```

You could do a hive -e 'show create table mytable' > /some/location/mytable.code.  Then you can just execute the code using a source call.

Good luck.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! Can't believe I missed that.